# Using Python to POST XML over HTTPS

Tags: python, xml, post, https

Let me start with I have successfully connected to my service end point. When I run my program, I get a `200 OK` and a text response of `XML request null.` These are both good things!  It's exactly what I get if I paste the URL of the service end point into a browser.

My question is, in my program I thought I was properly attaching my XML request payload to my POST.  However with the response of `XML request null.` indeed I am not.

```
xml = '''xml request here '''
host = "www.xmlendpoint.com"
url = "/service/endpoint"

def doRequest():
  conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host)

  headers = {"Content-type": "text/xml","Content-Length": "%d" % len(xml)}
  conn.request("POST", url, "", headers) 
  conn.send(xml)
  res = conn.getresponse()

  print res.status, res.reason
  print res.read()
  conn.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  doRequest()
```

Anything glaring wrong here?

Comment: ur not supposed to sign your questions.

Comment: I don't see where xml is defined?

Comment: It's only a question on where do I attach my structured XML so that it gets sent to the service. :)  However I have added them for compleatness!